# Can you use v2 features of the micro:bit when in Scratch Link mode, to create a 'game controller'?

Tags: mit-scratch, bbc-microbit

My daughter is excited about owning the v2 micro:bit as it has better features than the v1, but we cannot find a way to use these features when directly connected to Scratch. The situation I am referring to is when connected by USB to her laptop, and the buttons on the micro:bit can be read by the Scratch program *running on the laptop*, perhaps controlling a sprite on the screen. I think this is called the `Scratch Link` extension?

At present, connecting a micro:bit in this way means you can write a game in Scratch which runs on the laptop, but is instantly controlled by the micro:bit which you can hold in your hands like a Nintendo/Xbox 'controller'. My daughter's imagination is sparked by this, but...

**You cannot use the capacitive touch sensor, compass, microphone, speaker or pins 0/1/2 as output.**
You are limited to the A/B buttons, tilt sensor, shake sensor, and pins 0/1/2 as input.

Is there any way to get more of the v2 features to communicate with a Scratch program running on the laptop, without waiting for an update to `Scratch Link`? I tried to think whether I could write Javascript for the micro:bit so that it could send Bluetooth messages, and perhaps have Scratch listen to those, or perhaps there is another fudge to get around the limitations?

Answer (score 0):

These are the only micro:bit blocks that can be used in vanilla Scratch:

[image: List of Scratch Micro Bit Blocks]

In other words, no, it is not possible to utilize micro:bit sensors in Scratch without using external code in some way.